# Moving faster through space

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, time, coordinate-systems

I was reading through some articles today and I found,

> $$T'=T\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} $$
>
> **The faster you move through space, The slower you move through time.**

What does this statement mean?

Comment: It means the flow of time is not absolute. This is the outcome of the postulates of special relativity.

Comment: It means that you need to read/learn introductory special relativity

Comment: It means that time runs with the sped of light (or rather vise versa). As you approach the speed of light, you catch up with time, so time moves slower for you. You wouldn't notice this though, because your heart rate measured by your wrist watch would still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the faster you travel in space, the slower you move true Time.  On great example is the scenario where 2 twin brothers are born at the same age, and one leaves for space in a rocket ship travelling at light speed(or close to).  Upon returning 10 Earth years later(meaning 10 years calculated on earth), the boy in space would be younger than his brother on Earth.  This shows that it is indeed true that Time passes slower as one moves faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is at the heart of special relativity. Einstein's theory of special relativity rests on two main principles:

- The laws of physics, for all inertial (non-accelerating) reference frames, is always the same.
- The speed of light will, regardless of the reference frames used, always be some constant speed.

Each of these principles arises from specific experiments or other principles, the first being the principle of relativity itself (and the fact that it is kind of an axiom of science), and the second one is to explain the results of the Michelson–Morley experiment (see the appropriate Wikipedia article for a deeper explanation).

Simple thought experiments, like train-and-platform thought experiment (again, Wikipedia is the place to be), highlights the consequences of these principles.

In essence, in order for these principles to still hold, the progression of time for a moving frame of reference must slow down. Of course, if experiments determined that this is not the case, then special relativity would obviously not work. However, famous experiments, like the Hafele–Keating experiment, confirmed that the predictions made by special relativity are accurate.

In summary, because special relativity is experimentally proven to be true, and that the principles of special relativity imply that observing a reference frame traveling at some speed (progressing through space as per your question) relative to you means that you also observe their time progressing slower than yours. Of course, you cannot tell within your reference frame that you are moving, and only after you compare temporal progression can one tell the difference of the progression of time between observers.

tl:dr All of the goodness of special relativity is basically your answer.